# HTML coding order versus layout question

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, seo

I want to design a site with header, navigation part and content... for SEO purposes I want the coding in the order of content, header and navigation area... but when viewing the site we want to see header first then navigation area then content... is there any way doing this ?

Comment: I wouldn't do this; modern search engines recognize navigational parts (links in lists, etc.) and big blocks of real content.

Comment: Its really not worth it for seo. You will be facing tons of other bugs if you wish to use solutions such as absolute positioning. Besides, Google is smarter than that.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute positioning. This poses a bunch of other issues involving fixed heights, but gives you and idea of where to go. **Also, agree with comments, this is not a good approach and may even lie on the edge of "black hat" SEO techniques.**

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="Content"><div>
    <div id="Header"><div>
    <div id="Navigation"><div>
<div>

#Container
{
    position: relative;
}
#Content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
}
#Header
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0px;
}
#Navigation
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100px;
    top: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I doubt that it would be classed as a black hat technique as there's merit in organising a page that way for accessibility reasons. Getting a screen reader to the page content as quickly as possible is much better than subjecting the user to an interminable list of links that they're not interested in. Likewise, users who have to use puff-and-sip navigation do not want to have to step through all the menu links to get to the main page content.

Comment: These days WAI ARIA landmark roles solve the accessibility issue, so don't do it for those reasons either.